# Get latest version in go.mod if one of the requires is +incompatible

Tags: go, module, go-modules, mattermost

I have go.mod file, with require, one of them if `github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server v5.11.1+incompatible` but there is a new version of library in github, `5.17.1`.

I download latest version and work with it, but when i run `go mod init` my go.mod contains `5.11.1+incompatible` version.

How do I configure the go.mod files to use the latest version ?

Answer (score 1):

use `replace` in go.mod

```
replace github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server v5.11.1+incompatible => github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server v5.17.1
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't work, now i fixed this. I use mattermost-server and trouble was in that library, i wrote to mattermost dev. team, and they said that they know aboute this bug, and i need to use version 0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all prune the no-more-necessart dependencies using `go mod tidy`. Now, update all direct and indirect packages to the latest (minor) version with `go get -u ./...` where the `go.mod` file is located.